# Is it possible to run a .exe in windows through pgAgent?

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgagent

My company currently applies PostgreSQL 10 and windows server 2008 OS.

I need to run a C wrote calculation program in .exe file each month.

However, it is not perfect to double click and run it every month. Furthermore, I would like to be able to run it at anytime where most of the resources are free (like mid-night). So I would like to ask if any of the following would be possible?

1. Setup a job in pgAgent to auto-run .exe file each month?
2. And is there a way to get returned info from the running results?

Thanks for anyone who gives any clue.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler is worth a look..

Comment: Thank you, would you like to post your answer so I can accept it?? @JGH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Task Scheduler would be better suited for this task. You can select your .exe, set a run date/time and frequency. If you provide a user/password, it can run the task even if you are not logged in. See [here](https://onlinehelp.cloud.telenet.be/article.php?id=1097) for a tutorial.